# reading double nested xml

Tags: c#, xml, nested

I'm trying to read the following XML file

```
<Tabellen>
<Header>
    <Tables>
        <Table>SW_RL</Table>
            <Fields>
                <Field>KeyVeld</Field>
                <Type>Alpha</Type>
                <Size>100</Size>
                <SubType>st_none</SubType>
            </Fields>
            <Fields>
                <Field>ErrorCode</Field>
                <Type>Alpha</Type>
                <Size>50</Size>
                <SubType>st_none</SubType>
            </Fields>
            <Fields>
                <Field>Description</Field>
                <Type>Memo</Type>
                <Size>100</Size>
                <SubType>st_none</SubType>
            </Fields>
        </Tables>
</Header>
<Header>
    <Tables>
        <Table>SW_RH</Table>
    <Fields>
        <Field>DocNum</Field>
        <Type>Numeric</Type>
        <Size>0</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>PaymentTerms</Field>
        <Type>Numeric</Type>
        <Size>0</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>DocDate</Field>
        <Type>Date</Type>
        <Size>0</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>Contract_Start</Field>
        <Type>Date</Type>
        <Size>0</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>Contract_End</Field>
        <Type>Date</Type>
        <Size>0</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>CardCode</Field>
        <Type>Alpha</Type>
        <Size>40</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>CardName</Field>
        <Type>Alpha</Type>
        <Size>100</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>BillToAddress</Field>
        <Type>Alpha</Type>
        <Size>100</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>ShipToAddress</Field>
        <Type>Alpha</Type>
        <Size>100</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>NumAtCard</Field>
        <Type>Alpha</Type>
        <Size>100</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>BillingPeriod</Field>
        <Type>Alpha</Type>
        <Size>10</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>      
    </Fields>
    <Fields>
        <Field>AdvanceBilling</Field>
        <Type>Alpha</Type>
        <Size>10</Size>
        <SubType>st_none</SubType>
    </Fields>
    </Tables>
</Header>
</Tabellen>
```

Current code

```
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
xmldoc.Load(directory + "\\Server_Config.xml");
XmlNodeList xmlNodelist = null;
XmlNodeList xmlNodelist2 = null;

xmlNodelist = xmldoc.SelectNodes("Tabellen/Header/Tables");
foreach (XmlNode mnode in xmlNodelist)
{
    MessageBox.Show(mnode["Table"].InnerText, "ok");
     //create table

    xmlNodelist2 = xmldoc.SelectNodes("Tabellen/Header/Tables/Fields");
    foreach (XmlNode mnode2 in xmlNodelist2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(mnode2["Field"].InnerText, "ok");
        // create fields
    }

}
```

The general idea is to create 2 tables
Table 1: RL containing 3 fields
Table 2 :RH containing 12 fields

But actually the result is both tables containing 15 fields

What am I doing wrong ??

Comment: How are you reading the xml?  `DataSet.ReadXML`?

Answer (score 1):

Linq2Xml is easier to use.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("myfile.xml");
var tables = xDoc.Descendants("Header")
                .Select(h => new
                {
                    Table  = h.Descendants("Table").First().Value,
                    Fields = h.Descendants("Fields")
                              .Select(f=>new{
                                    Field = f.Element("Field").Value,
                                    Type = f.Element("Type").Value,
                                    Size = f.Element("Size").Value,
                                    SubType = f.Element("SubType").Value
                               })
                              .ToList()
                })
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlNodelist2 = xmldoc.SelectNodes("Tabellen/Header/Tables/Fields");
```

should be

```
xmlNodelist2 = mnode.SelectNodes("Fields");
```

Otherwise you select all the Fields in the XML, not just the ones under the current table.

(I've not tested the code however)